# Is it safe to Install Debian, and possible to go back?

Tags: debian, system-installation

I already use bosslinux and want to try Debian (by installing Debian) 
would I be able to delete it completely afterwards?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you mean, "Can I install Debian *in place of* BOSS and then later switch back?", then yes.  However, you won't be able to go back to your old BOSS installation -- you'll have to install it from new again.

If you mean, "Can I install Debian on an unused partition and later remove it?", then yes again, but you don't need to remove it, and perhaps should not, because:

- When you install, the installer will (I think by default) set up the whole drive (as in, all partitions) to use a `grub` (grub is the *bootloader* which loads the OS kernel) that is installed with everything else.  This will allow you to select from a list of installed operating systems at boot time, but if you decide you don't want to use debian anymore and just erase it, you'll also have erased the grub used for your whole hard drive...whoops, now you can't boot anything.  That's fixable, but you probably don't want the hassle.  So either:

  1. Use the grub you already have when installing.  The installer *should* detect this and present you with the option, but it may not.  So doing things this way is a little bit complicated.
  2. Just leave the Debian installation there until you want to use that partition for something else.  If that "something else" is another installation, do that and it should install its own grub and make that the active one.  Otherwise, you will have to re-install grub on the BOSS installation.
- The reason you don't need to "remove" Debian (or whatever) is because if you don't want to use it, just don't use it.  In that case, it is just taking up space on your drive, and when you want to use that space, you can go ahead and overwrite the data -- keeping in mind the caveat mentioned above.

**To summarize:** The only significant issue when removing a linux installation is the bootloader, grub.  Grub is part of the installation, but it is also what gives you a menu at boot time, allowing you to choose *a different* installation from the same hard disk.  Even if there is only one partition that you actually want to use, if your active grub is on some other partition, you better leave that alone until you replace it.

If you want to resize/delete/create partitions, use **[gparted](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GParted)**.  Just don't do it using an OS installation on the disk you want to change.  In other words, if you want to change your hard drive, boot a Live CD and use the `gparted` there.  You don't have to do this before a new install, as the installer will probably invoke gparted for you at some point and ask how you want your partitions laid out, etc.